# Html Button trigger PHP code

Tags: php, html

I have a `demo.php`, in it I have a button:

```
<?php

include('../library/Requests.php');

Requests::register_autoloader();

function get_data(){
    $request = Requests::post('http://localhost:8000/api/groups/list/', array(), null);

    var_dump($request);
}

?>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

How can I trigger the `get_data` method in my `demo.php`? Who can tell me the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have you to look simple things...

```
<?php

include('../library/Requests.php');

Requests::register_autoloader();
// check whether form is submitted or not on same page if submitted then call get_data() function
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
     get_data();
}
function get_data(){
    $request = Requests::post('http://localhost:8000/api/groups/list/', array(), null);

    var_dump($request);
}


?>

// make form that could send request
<form action="" method="post">
     <button name="submitBtn" type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can I do not use the <form>?

Comment: You can make use of ajax ... means you must send request to server form HTML